# Link or button to open the media manager from frontend

Tags: uploads, media-library, front-end

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to add a link or button that will open the media manager/library on the front end of the site? I don't need to select images for insert or to select images as featured, I simply want to allow my users to upload and edit their media within the library without having to go the backend to do so.

Is this possible? I've Googled quite a bit and can't seem to find anyone else who's trying to do this so I turned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtually all the core files and scripts that WordPress uses for displaying the media library are within the `wp-admin` folder, plus it uses various admin-only hooks, so using this on the front-end is pretty much out of the question.

It's not difficult to allow users to upload to the media library from the front end (either writing your own system or using a plugin like Gravity Forms which has this functionality built-in), but providing all the media management functionality is going to be a very big task indeed.

Comment: Darn, I had a feeling that might be the case. I'm not even gonna try, what a headache that would probably be. OK, onward to building my custom solution! Thanks for confirmation.